# HTAcess 301 Redirect URL Parameter that has a Wildcard?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, querystringparameter

I have taken over a website and have rewritten the gallery facility to use the Fancy light-box plugin instead of separate pages for each image, 42 pages in total, i.e gallery now only consists of a single webpage now.

Therefore, I added lines to the HTAcess file for all the relevant 301s, 42 times :( :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^view=14$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewGallery\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/gallery/?view=14 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Is there a way to use a wildcard to capture the gallery number, in this case 14, and shorten the section to just single entry in the HTAccess file?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^view=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewGallery\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/gallery/?view=%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

This is essentially what you have except you change the regex for the query string to capture the ID, then you can backreference it using `%1` in the rule's target.

But, an easier way to do it is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^view=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewGallery\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/gallery/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Simply remove the `?view=%1` part altogether. The rewrite engine will automatically append the query string to the end as long as you don't have a `?` in the target.

Comment: Brilliant, worked first time. Definitely remember this snippet for next time, many thanks. @Jon-Lin